# Processing function millis() not returning an integer

Tags: processing

So, first off, I am using the [Python Mode for Processing](http://py.processing.org/). And in my code I have something like this:

```
limit = millis() + 10
while millis() < limit:
    pass
```

I am trying to do something similar to Python's time.sleep function, but the value of `limit` increases as `millis()` does. `limit` is always 10 milliseconds greater than how long the window has been open. How do I get the value of limit to be a constant?

Comment: The `millis()` function returns the number of milliseconds the sketch has been running. So that's what I would expect the value of `limit` to be. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinWorkman surely `limit` shouldn't be changing after the while loop is entered?

Comment: @AlexHall That's why you should post an [mcve]. The answer is that it's probably not, but that you've got something else going on in your code. We can't really comment on that without seeing more code. You'll have better luck if you narrow it down to as few lines as possible while preserving the behavior. Posting your whole project is probably too much code, but what you've posted isn't enough to really be sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

As @KevinWorkman already mentioned you should post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) otherwise is hard for us to help you.

Right now I can only suggest you 2 following options. But they are only hot fixes. Instead you should study more about `draw` function (furthermore: `noLoop` `lopp` `reDraw` `frameRate`) and how processing works so you can avoid problems like this. Use this [documentation](https://processing.org/reference/) for descriptions.

**1)** You can use python function `time.sleep(0.01)` instead your limit while combo. Don't forget to `import time`

**2)** You can use busy-looping

```
t = millis()
limit = t + 1000000
while t < limit:
    t += 1
```